# Python Selenium open URL in same Firefox window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Selenium to open a Firefox browser and go to a URL.  The function I am using to do this is...

```
def openurl_function():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://www.example.com')
```

When I run the function it always opens a new instance of FireFox, is there a way to have it to just open using the same browser instance?

Currently if I run the function 10 times then I get 10 FireFox browsers open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just keep reusing the same `driver`. You are creating a new browser, every time you call

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Also, because you never `quit()` on your driver, you will probably have all the browsers stay open as orphans because you deleted the handle to them when you created a new browser.

Comment: So would I need to move the driver = webdriver.Firefox() outside of the function so it only runs the once?

Comment: Yes. Just create the object in global context and pass it to your function every time (or use an object property if it's within a class).